# switch( i ^ 3). what does this mean?

Tags: java

I cannot understand to why this syntax does not generate any kind of compile time or run time errors ?

```
int i=2;

switch(i ^ 3){       ---- > this part
 case 8: System.out.print("Eight"); break;
 default: System.out.print("Default");
}
```

It prints Default, so what does this ( i ^ 3 ) do in the switch condition ?

Comment: it´s a bitwise xor

Comment: Worst way of writing `if(i == 11) {...} else {...}` ever!

Answer (score 1):

`i ^ 3` is i XOR 3 (2 XOR 3), which is 1 (10 XOR 11 is 1). It's not a power operator, so it doesn't return 8. Therefore the default section of the switch statement is reached.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is equal to `2`.

2^3 = 1. (XOR operation).

10  //2
 11  // 3 (XOR)
  --
  01 //1

So, it sets the value of 1 for the switch condition.

Answer (score 0):

^  is Bitwise XOR    where `i ^ 3`  generate integer result.